# How to iterate coefficients in polynomial regression model?

Tags: machine-learning

I understand what the polynomial regression is trying to achieve (best fit via least squares method) but I can find no algorithm for finding the coefficient in the polynomial. Brute force is not viable and it's the only solution I can think of. Is there a way to iterate the coefficients? Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand what you mean, but if you are asking on how to get the coefficients, it should be easy for every regression algorithm implementation to get the final weights back. 
Here you have some nice example using ridge regression to fit a polynomial with sklearn:
[ridge regression to fit a polynomial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_polynomial_interpolation.html).

And if you check the documentation ([sklearn.linear_model.Ridge](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.Ridge.html#sklearn.linear_model.Ridge)) you will see there is an attribute named `coef_` used to get the weight vector(s).

EDIT: Sklearn is a python library for machine learning: [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/index.html).